# How do i retain the content of a line while unmatching all lines before the first and after the last occurance of a particular string?

Tags: awk

i am using a awk script which removes all the lines before the first and after the last occurance of a string - "Lecture" in my case and removes any blank lines in between while also retaining any non lecture line in between

**Awk Script**

```
awk '
/Lecture/{
  found=1
}
found && NF{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(val){
    match(val,/.*Lecture [0-9]+/)
    print substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  }
}'  1.txt
```

**cat 1.txt**

```
My Dashboard
Fnfjfjf. random test
00:50

1:01:56
My Notes
No data found.

                                
Change Language                                                                                                                  + English                                                          

Submit


Estimation of Working Capital Lecture 1

Estimation of Working Capital Lecture 2

Estimation of Working Capital Lecture 3
Retain this line 
Money Market Lecture 254

Money Market Lecture 255

Money Market Lecture 256

International Trade Lecture 257

International Trade Lecture 258

International Trade Lecture 259B Some random text gndgnkdbkdlbkmdbmldbm
Terms And Conditions
84749473837373
Random text fifjfofifofjfkfkf
```

**Expected output**

```
Estimation of Working Capital Lecture 1
Estimation of Working Capital Lecture 2
Estimation of Working Capital Lecture 3
Retain this line
Money Market Lecture 254
Money Market Lecture 255
Money Market Lecture 256
International Trade Lecture 257
International Trade Lecture 258
International Trade Lecture 259B Some random text gndgnkdbkdlbkmdbmldbm
```

**Issue in existing script**
It works almost well but doesnt retains the content of the line having last occurance of string "Lecture" ( ie it ends the last line as *International Trade Lecture 259* instead of *International Trade Lecture 259B Some random text gndgnkdbkdlbkmdbmldbm* . i only want the awk script to remove all blank lines and delete all lines before the first and after the last occurance of the string "Lecture" while not changing anything in between and retaining any non Lecture line ( else i would have just used grep )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples. Also its OP's existing code I have tweaked its regex to match till last occurrence of string `Lecture`

```
awk '
/Lecture/{
  found=1
}
found && NF{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(val){
    match(val,/.*Lecture[^\n]*/)
    print substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation of OP's code improvement:*** Since OP is keep adding line's values to variable named `val`. OP's code is not picking last line so I changed the regex to pick line till string `Lecture`'s last occurrence and till new line comes after that to match the last missing line mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be

```
awk '
    /Lecture/ {
        seen = 1
        print buffer (buffer != "" ? ORS : "") $0
        buffer = ""
        next
    }
    
    seen && NF {
        buffer = buffer (buffer != "" ? ORS : "") $0
    }
' 1.txt
```

This prints out the accumulated lines whenever the line read matches the `Lecture`.